# Andengine: destinguish between OnAreaTouched and OnSceneTouched

Tags: java, android, andengine, game-engine

#### Hi Everyone,

in the game I develop with AndEngine, there are a lot of sprites running around. Now every of this sprites has a **`TouchArea`** registered to the scene, because I display some informations about the sprite when it is touched. The Scene itself has a **`OnSceneTouchListener`** that I use for moving the camera around and to zoom.

My problem is, that every time the user moves the camera (by touching the display somewhere and moving his finger around) the **`OnAreaTouched()`** method of any sprite, that is accidentally under the finger, gets called, when the movement is finished (finger gets lifted). I already limited the triggering events to `event.getAction()==UP` (before it was a real mess of called touchAreas) but this is not enough. If the user is zooming or moving the camera, the sprites touchAreas should not be activated.

Is there any way I can distinguish between an `OnAreaTouched`-event and an `OnSceneTouched`-event? Which one is called first and can I suppress the other?

#### This is my `OnSceneTouched()` method (simplified):

```
public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene scene, final TouchEvent event) {
    boolean isZooming = event.getMotionEvent().getPointerCount() >= 2;
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // REMEMBER FIRST TOUCHPOINT, TO KNOW IN WHICH DIRECTION TO MOVE
        this.touchPoint = new Point(event.getMotionEvent().getX(), event.getMotionEvent().getY());  
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        if (isZooming) {
            // DO SOME ZOOM STUFF
        } else {
            // DO SOME MOVEMENT STUFF
        }
        return true;
    }
```

OK, actually this is not very interesting -  but as you can see I always return  `true` to signal that the touch event was handled. Still the `OnAreaTouched()` gets called

#### This is a typical `OnAreaTouched()` Method of a sprite:

```
public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent touchEvent, float touchAreaLocalX, float touchAreaLocalY) {
    if (touchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_UP) {
          // DISPLAY INFORMATION ABOUT THE SPRITE
          return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You see, there is nothing special to it. So I hope someone can help me out here to find a solution how to suppress the `OnAreaTouch`-event when the `OnSceneTouch`-event should be used. Maybe I can somehow catch the `event.getAction()==UP` in the `OnSceneTouched()`-Method??

I hope I could explain the problem good enough for you to understand (sorry, it's not that easy for me : ). Any help is much appreciated, and thank you for you time!

regards
     Christoph

#### edit:

After experimenting with MahdeTo's suggestion to tag the event somehow I found out the following:

- the `TouchEvent` that triggers the `OnSceneTouchEvent()` Method is not the same as the one triggering the `OnAreaTouched()` Method.
- `OnAreaTouched()`  gets called 20 ms later than `OnSceneTouchEvent()`
- the event calling `OnAreaTouched()` starts actually when the user puts his finger down on the display (than he moves it around and the `OnSceneTouchEvent()` gets called multiple times), when he then lifts his finger the first event stops and gets handled. (I tried it out by measuring the time)

So I came up with the solution to measure how long a touch event lasted. If the event is longer than 200 ms, I guess the user wanted not to simply *click* but move or zoom (because these actions usually take longer). So now the `OnAreaTouched()` method gets only called when someone really meant to *click* and not accidentally swiped over the area.

**but** it's still not a good solution and I would really appreciate if anyone knows more about controlling such events.

thank you

Comment: How do you dispatch the touch events to the separate sprites?

Comment: I don't really dispatch them. The thouchAreas (of the sprites) are registerd in the scene and therefore get triggered whenever the touchevent is within any of these touchareas.

Comment: Try adding a tag on the event on the scene touch, and checking it on the sprites before proceeding. If it's akin to the motion event of android they have multiplexed flags for example edge flags have values 1,2,4,8 you can easily set 16 as yours without breaking any other functionality and at the same time getting your differentiation if it's the same instance of event being passed around.

Comment: Thank you for your tip! I set the edgeFlags to 16 as you told me, but when logging the edgeFlag in the touchArea method, it returns 0. So I guess it's another event. But now I am confused. How many touch events get triggered at the same time? is it maybe an event that is only 10 ms newer than the motion event I handled before?

Comment: That's a good question ! you can answer it by having a static collection and pushing the events there then debugging it and seeing how many. Maybe then we can know what really happens.

Comment: @Christoph, i know i am talking irrelevant, but can you help me in achieving zoom effect in onAreaTouch method of each sprite. I am very new to andEngine, and not getting that piece of code to handle multi touch onAreaTouched Listener. As u mentioned your code above which is incomplete, can u paste it completely? Thanks in advance, i am badly in need..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have recently written a fairly complicated application using touch controls - pressing buttons on the screen, pinch zooming, rotating and moving objects with two fingers and more. What I ended up doing was iteratively improving the application and adding rules controlling how to respond to different combinations of touch events. Whenever something was wrong, I recorded the sequence of TouchEvents and added rules so that the misbehaving action was handled.

You can also create boolean switches that prevent the `onAreaTouched` to execute, just add a condition that, for example if you want to touch an object, checks whether `doNotTouchObject` is true or false.

Another thing I found useful were touch mode switchers. I wrote several methods that completely change the behavior when user touches the screen. I believe you can switch them on the go, so it should be possible to call `scene.setOnAreaTouchListener(touchListener)` while you are touching the screen.

Since un/registering touch areas is blazing fast, simply unregistering certain touch areas while you perform some action is a possibility. After the action is completed, reregister them again.

I used a combination of all of the above and it works rather well, but it is essential to keep the code clean, otherwise debugging or implementing new features will be a pain.

Comment: You are right, thank you. Actually this is how I do things now. Since I couldn't find a proper solution to distinguish between onArea- and onScene-touchEvents, I now set flags. So at the end the whole onSceneTouch method is a sequence of if conditions. It works quite well, and I try to keep my code clean - although it still bothers my that there are two different events triggered when the user touches the screen one time. Passing such an event hierarchically through the classes (onSceneTouch - onAreaTouch ....) would make more sense to me.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for mScene.setTouchAreaBindingEnabled(true); That could do the trick, I don't use it though so I cannot tell you whether there are any quirks to be aware of.

Comment: @JohnEye , i know i am talking irrelevant, but can you help me in achieving zoom effect in onAreaTouch method of each sprite. I am very new to andEngine, and not getting that piece of code to handle multi touch onAreaTouched Listener.I tried to do this way, but this didnot work.
case TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN: isZooming=pSceneTouchEvent.getMotionEvent().getPointerCount() >= 2;
scaleFactor++;
break;
case TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
if(isZooming)
{
face2.setScale(scaleFactor)
}
else
{
this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth()/2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight()/2);
}

Answer (score 2):

1. maybe you can use the TouchDetector.
   use the clickDetector instead of process TouchUp event, then only the detected click event is processed by the sprites;
   use the scroll detector for the Scene Scrolling too;
2. enable the SceneTouchListenerBinding and TouchAreaBinding will also help you to by pass all the unintended in-progress events.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't really aware that there are so many possibilities! I am going to lock deeper into using them. So you say the ClickDetector for the sprites and Scroll- and ZoomDetector for the Scene? It sounds good, although my first tests weren't that successful. I tried the PinchZoomDetector and in one scene it worked, but in another it just didn't.. well so much for clean code :) Thank you, I'll tell you how it went